# Changing code block preferences for properties to prefer block body (using .editorconfig file)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community, editorconfig

In my .editorconfig file I have this line `csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = false:suggestion` but whenever I try to apply the quick actions suggestion to use it, it doesn't work and it causes a problem.

Here is the message that I have got:
[image]

I am using the following version of Visual Studio:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.2 (26430.16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = false:suggestion` is working perfectly now.

The problem seems to be solved now but I don't know how it was fixed.

Note that I am using the following version of Visual Studio now: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.3.3